# Remove "Image 1" from picture Caption in Doxygen RTF

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I'm producing rtf output from doxygen and have several images/pictures embedded in the document.  The issue is that every image/picture caption starts with "Image 1".  I did not put that in my caption, so I'm wondering how to remove that from the output.

Using Doxygen 1.8.17

Example Markdown contents:

```
SUBSYSTEM DESIGN SPECIFICATIONS {#Breath-DeliverySubDesignSpecRtf}
=================================

These are the specifications for the Breath-Delivery Subsystem

BREATHRECORD_SDD_01

> For neonatal patients, air pressure signals shall be computed as shown on Figure 4. 
> ![Figure 4: Optimal Airway Pressure estimates](media/OptimalAirwayPressureEstimates.png)
```

Results in rtf output:
[image: rtf Output]

How do I remove the "Image 1" text from the caption?

Every Image/Picture in the doc starts with "Image 1" also.  It's not incrementing this number automatically.

[image: rtf output 2]

Comment: You placed "Figure 4" explicitly in the caption of the image, it is a bit strange to have "Figure 4" as first number. Doxygen will automatically place "Image #" and the counting will be don by doxygen / the RTF showing software. That said It might be possible in the showing software to modify the caption / its style.

Comment: @albert The reason I have "Figure 4" explicitly placed in the caption is because I'm referring to it in the text.  Unfortunately, this was part of the automated process when converting my word docs to Markdown.  There are literally 1000's of Figures across dozens of documents, so I don't have a way to update those without manually doing it for all documents.

Comment: @albert also, it puts "Image 1" for every image in the document.  It's not auto incrementing the number. see further example listed above.

Comment: That the convertor from word to markdown places the `Figure..` in it is not that nice. But I think that when you want to have a list of images you will need to edit it out (a bit of one time work ... I think you will have to have had to do some other editing as well when you did the conversion) . Regarding referencing to an image you could use the doxygen `\anchor` and `\ref` commands. The default name for an image is "Image 1" but by regenerating indexes etc in the rtf viewer this should automatically be corrected.

Comment: @albert Unfortunately, it would be too much work to edit it out for me at this point.  However, I think it would be a useful feature to NOT have doxygen try to generate auto incrementing Image # references for RTF output.  If it would just print exactly what I put into the image caption, I would have any issues. Does this need to be a feature request in GitHub?  Is there a way to manipulate Doxgyen config or style sheets?

Comment: So you want to transport the work to doxygen. It would require an extra configuration setting so that code from other users is not broken. I would need an enhancement issue at github, but I'm not optimistic that it would be changed soon. Regarding the styles, I didn't see the a reference to images in the doxygen style sheet for rtf (`doxygen -w rtf styleSheetFile`), when having it (when possible) in the style sheet this would be a better way to go.

Comment: @albert I do understand you would need to be backwards compatible, but I'm not asking for extra work in doxygen.  Maybe I'm confused, because this doesn't happen on the HTML output.  Doxygen doesn't add "Image #" to the pictures for the HTML output.  It only seems to do this for RTF output, which seems strange and not consistent.  What I'm really wanting doxygen to do is NOT add more than what is already in the Markdown when creating RTF output.